# Requesting help on change sets to add custom check box field to outbound change sets

Tags: change-set

How can we add a custom check box field of case object to outbound change set.  because I don't find the check box field in the custom field component of the change set.Can someone please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your custom checkbox is part of another item that is moving over, like a page layout or workflow, you can click the View Dependent button to see it in that list.